# Comparing two sequential values in order to do an operation within sequence in another field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I have a shapefile representing points along a line. I have the downstream distance of each point on their respective line. What I would like to do is sequence the two fields in the attribute table based on the spatially joined stream id `arcid` and downstream distance `DSDistance`. I would then like to run an operation such that the difference in 'DSDistance' between two points with the same stream id is calculated:

```
fid    arcid    DSDistance  to    fid   arcid    DSDistance   Distance
1        1          10             1      1          10         10
2        5          10             4      1          15         5
3        3          7              3      3          7          7
4        1          15             2      5          10         10
5        5          20             5      5          20         10
6        5          27             6      5          27         7
```

The code I have written to do this operation is below:

```
fields = ["arcid","DSDistance"]
sql_orderby = "ORDER BY" + ", ".join("{} ASC".format(field) for field in fields)
with arcpy.UpdateCursor(home + '/PourPoints1.shp',"",sql_clause=(None, sql_orderby)) as cursor: 
firstTime = True
for row in cursor:
    if firstTime:
        previous = row.getValue('arcid') 
        previous1 = row.getValue('DSDistance') 
        firstTime = False
    else:
        current = row.getValue('arcid')
        if current == previous:
            row.setValue('Distance', row.getValue('DSDistance') - previous1)
            rows.updateRow(row)
            previous1 = row.getValue('DSDistance')
        else:
            row.setValue('Distance', row.getValue('DSDistance'))
            rows.updateRow(row)

del row
del rows
```

I have written this code from [sort rows, subtract current from next, ...](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/need-python-example-sort-rows-subtract-current/td-p/329388) and [updating field on previous row](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186382/arcpy-da-updatecursor-updating-field-based-on-the-previous-row).

Update using the solution below I receive an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "H:\Projects\260\Storm Water\GIS\PythonScript\table\BasinScript.py", line 267, in 
> inCursor.insertRow(newRow)
> SystemError: error return without exception set

My workspace destination is a folder

```
home = r'H:/Projects/260/Storm Water/GIS/PythonScript/Workspace'

# Path to input table
tblPath = home + '/PourPoints1.shp'

# Create a defaultdict
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
dd1 = collections.defaultdict(list)

# create an output table
print("Creating output table...")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.CreateTable_management(home,"tblOutput.dbf")
arcpy.AddField_management(home + '/tblOutput.dbf',"arcid","LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(home+ '/tblOutput.dbf',"DSDistance","LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(home+ '/tblOutput.dbf',"Dist","LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(home+ '/tblOutput.dbf',"TARGET_FID","LONG")

# read data into dictionary
print("Reading input table...")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tblPath,["arcid","DSDistance","TARGET_FID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcid = row[0]
        dist = row[1]
        dd[arcid].append(dist)
        fid = row[2]
        dd1[arcid].append(fid)

for k, v in dd1.items():
    dd[k] = [dd[k], v]

# sort dictionary by key into tuples of lists
sortedlist = sorted(dd.items())

# Process sortedlist
print("Writing to output table...")
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(home + '/tblOutput.dbf',["arcid","DSDistance","Dist","TARGET_FID"]) as inCursor:
    for tup in sortedlist:
        arcid = tup[0] # e.g. 5
        disList = sorted(tup[1][0]) # e.g [10,20,27]
        distList1 = tup[1][1]

        if len(disList) > 1:
            # create a second list that is an offset of disList
            offList = list(disList) # Copy list
            offList.insert(0,0) # insert zero at start of list
            offList.pop() # remove last value, so using example above you will have [0,10,20]

            # Compute offset value
            zipobj = zip(disList,offList)
            diffList = list()
            for i1,i2 in zipobj:
                diffList.append(i1-i2)

            # Write output to table, here we are accessing the values in the list by the index position i
            for i in range(len(disList)):
                newRow = (arcid,disList[i],diffList[i],disList1[i])
                inCursor.insertRow(newRow)
        else:
            # Just one entry in input table so write it out
            newRow = (arcid,disList[0],disList[0],disList1[0])
            inCursor.insertRow(newRow)
```

Update:
Adding the tblOutput path extension `.dbf` successfully produced a table with the solution I was looking for. Modified the solution to bring across a unique field ID to make joining the output table to the shape file easier.

Update:
FelixIP's solution sets a warning:

> extract["DELTA"] = extract[chainageField].shift(-1)-extract[chainageField]
> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Update:
Updated the solution to bring a unique field from input table over to output table.

Comment: The first rule of ArcPy cursors is **Only use DA cursors**. The second rule is: **Don't trust ORDER BY to function on all data sources**.

Comment: The error may be down to the fact that you are creating an INFO table to store your output.  I don't know but maybe cursors don't work with them? You declare a folder location H:/Projects/260/Storm Water/GIS/PythonScript/Workspace and then you create a table called tblOutput and give it no file extension. A simple solution is to explicitly state its a dBase file by putting .dbf at the end of it. Try that? My original code creates a table inside a geodatabase hence no file name extension.

Comment: Learning how to functionally apply python to spatial data. Thank you for clarification of changing the path name. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the code you need:

```py
import arcpy
import collections

# Path to input table
tblPath = r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\testtable"

# Create a defaultdict
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)

# create an output table
print("Creating output table...")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.CreateTable_management(r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb","tblOutput")
arcpy.AddField_management(r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\tblOutput","arcid","LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\tblOutput","DSDist","LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\tblOutput","Dist","LONG")

# read data into dictionary
print("Reading input table...")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tblPath,["arcid","DSDist"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcid = row[0]
        dist = row[1]
        dd[arcid].append(dist)

# sort dictionary by key into tuples of lists
sortedlist = sorted(dd.items())

# Process sortedlist
print("Writing to output table...")
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\tblOutput",["arcid","DSDist","Dist"]) as inCursor:
    for tup in sortedlist:
        arcid = tup[0] # e.g. 5
        disList = sorted(tup[1]) # e.g [10,20,27]

        if len(disList) > 1:
            # create a second list that is an offset of disList
            offList = list(disList) # Copy list
            offList.insert(0,0) # insert zero at start of list
            offList.pop() # remove last value, so using example above you will have [0,10,20]

            # Compute offset value
            zipobj = zip(disList,offList)
            diffList = list()
            for i1,i2 in zipobj:
                diffList.append(i1-i2)

            # Write output to table, here we are accessing the values in the list by the index position i
            for i in range(len(disList)):
                newRow = (arcid,disList[i],diffList[i])
                inCursor.insertRow(newRow)
        else:
            # Just one entry in input table so write it out
            newRow = (arcid,disList[0],disList[0])
            inCursor.insertRow(newRow)
```

It works by reading the data into a dictionary, sorting, creating an off-set version of the list of distances and then computes the difference by taking advantage of the zip() function to iterate over both lists and finally writing it back to the output table.

Results are shown below:

[image: Results]

The simplest (path of least resistance) solution to join back the offset distance to the original pour point data is to use the Make Query Table tool. For this to work both the pour point and tblOutput need to be in the same File GeoDatabase. Then run the tool as shown below to create a temporary layer which you can right click on and export from the TOC.

[image: Make Query Table tool]

Results are:

[image: Results]

Comment: Ill give this a shot. Will the tblOutput be a new shape file with the adjusted table or will I need to join the table to the old shape file?

Comment: Another way to ask this is, would it be possible to instead create three new fields in my shape file and process the sorted list within those three fields in my current point shape file?

Comment: I tried using your code but it throws a `SystemError`:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x", line 267, in <module>
    inCursor.insertRow(newRow)
SystemError: error return without exception set```

Comment: I cannot comment on the error until I see the version of code that you are running and all the full path names. This code is designed to create a table in a file geodatabase, which must already exist and in my case in a folder called scratch. You could join the output of the table back to your shapefile if you so desired, or adapt the code to write it back into the shapefile.

Comment: To make the join process easier, what modifications do you suggest to keep a unique field ID from the shape file across to the tblOutput?

Comment: Correct, often people use the objectid which is not guaranteed to be sequential so causes all sorts of problems. So you need to create a second id field which is in both tables then you can join them.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to move across the `fid` field? The update ive made moves it across but does not create a difference between the two points.

Comment: I'm not sure what you desire is logical because the original input pour point dataset is in the row order you have but you want your output to be sorted. How can you attach a sorted dataset to an unsorted dataset? You can't. You can use the sort tool to physical reorder the rows by arcid and DSDist in your pour point dataset. If the output table and pour point were both in the same file geodatabase you could use the make query layer tool to join on fid and arcid to give you that 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: You adding fid into `dd[arcid,fid].append(dist)` makes no sense to the logic as the dictionary is sorted by arcid.

Comment: I changed the table in my question to reflect what I am talking about. The fid field is sorted with arcid and DSDist the question is how to have that field value move (while sorted) to the output table.

Comment: @rweber - see my updated answer. The path you were going down editing my code will lead to all sorts of problems with processing, a simple join will solve this if the data is in a file geodatabase.

Comment: This is great but how much processing would be required to create another dictionary with sorted fid creating a new column and appending that to the main dictionary? Especially if this process were to be automated.

Comment: Not much really (for me), a second dictionary tracking the uniqueness of the row, I had considered that approach but the path of least resistance and conceptually simpler is a simple table join as shown. You can call the Make table Query tool from python if you wish to automate all this. I leave that to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137291/discussion-between-rweber-and-hornbydd).

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect case for using pandas sort, shift and series math.

Picture shows input points and their distance along line:

[image]

This is points' table:

[image]

Script:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
fid, groupField, chainageField = ["OID@", "NEAR_FID","D_ALONG"]
DF = pd.DataFrame(arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("points",[fid, groupField, chainageField]))
DF.sort_values(by=[chainageField],inplace=True)

bigDict = {}
RIVERS = set(DF[groupField])
for river in RIVERS:
    extract = DF[DF[groupField]==river]
    extract["DELTA"] = extract[chainageField].shift(-1)-extract[chainageField]
    extract["DELTA"].fillna(0,inplace=True)
    for row in extract.itertuples():
        bigDict[row[1]]=row[-1]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("points",[fid,"DSDistance"]) as cursor:
    for oid,dsd in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow((oid,bigDict[oid]))
```

Output shows points labelled by their chainage and distance to next one downstream:

[image]

Updated shorter version of script:

```
import pandas as pd
fid, groupField, chainageField = ["OID@", "NEAR_FID","D_ALONG"]
DF = pd.DataFrame(arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("points",[fid, groupField, chainageField]))
DF.sort_values(by=[chainageField],inplace=True)
DF.set_index("OID@",inplace=True)

bigDict = {}
RIVERS = set(DF[groupField])
for river in RIVERS:
    extract = DF[DF[groupField]==river]
    DELTA = extract[chainageField].shift(-1)-extract[chainageField]
    DELTA.iloc[-1]=0
    smallDict = DELTA.to_dict()
    bigDict.update(smallDict)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("points",[fid,"DSDistance"]) as cursor:
    for oid,dsd in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow((oid,bigDict[oid]))
```

Comment: In your `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` call you have `"DSDistance"` but in your list of variables you use `"D_Along"`. For clarification, your `"D_along"` field is the distance along the line and the `"DSDistance"` is the downstream distance between points, correct?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: I updated my post with an error from the solution you provided when I integrated it into my code. I wasn't sure how to rectify it.

Comment: Did you get correct result? No such warning when I ran it from map document

Comment: It threw the error before finishing and didn't output the results.